# Can I test if my script is run with bokeh serve?

Tags: bokeh

I have a script that I want to run with `bokeh serve` to display and evaluate results, but I also want to be able to run the same script without bokeh. There's some internal logic that depends on which mode it's running, so I need to be able tot test if the script is launched with `bokeh serve` or without.

I tried evaluating `curdoc()`, assuming that when run without `bokeh serve` it would return `None`, but in both cases it returns some object, so I can't simply do an `if curdoc()`.

So far I didn't find any reference to this kind of test in the bokeh docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if an application is being run though a `bokeh` server by inspecting the `__name__` of the file.

If I have an `app.py` file that I can run either via `boke serve --show app.py` or `python app.py`. Depending on how the script is run, the `__name__` will be different.

**app.py**

```py
if __name__.startswith('bokeh'):
    print(__name__, 'running via bokeh server')

else:
    print(__name__, 'not running via bokeh server')
```

[image]

Comment: When app code is run, a new module object is created for it to run in, and the module gets a name like `bokeh_<long unique id>`. I would caution that this is internal, undocumented behavior, however. We don't have any plans to change it but I can't guarantee it won't ever change, either. I'd encourage someone to submit a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) regarding the addition of a documented, supported API for this use-case.

Comment: this is helpful and useful enough for development scripts. sometimes `python app.py` is needed and sometimes `bokeh serve --show app.py` is better.